# How to get Hotkey for background MFC app to show

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, hotkeys

I create a MFC App that can hide (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) or show (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) if I press hot key. By default it's hidden when startup. I search the solution and find it:

```
// OnPaint to paint the app and hide
void CAppDlg::OnPaint()
{
    ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}

// Register the Hotkey when app startup
BOOL CAppDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    RegisterHotKey(CAppDlg::m_hWnd, 1001, MOD_SHIFT, 'A');
    RegisterHotKey(CAppDlg::m_hWnd, 1002, MOD_SHIFT, 'a');
}

// Get SHIFT+W to hide app again
BOOL CAppDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg){
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN){
        if (pMsg->wParam == 0x57){
            if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) {
                ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
            }   
        }
    }

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

// Get hotkey id (SHIFT+A) to show app
LRESULT CAppDlg::OnHotKey(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if (wParam == 1001 || wParam == 1002){
        ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This app will hide when startup, function `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` must be declared in `OnPaint()` function, if it's declared in `OnInitDialog()` it's not hidden. But if I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to show windows, it shows and hide right away (because of `OnPaint()` function is recalled). How can I do now? Thank all

Comment: As I commented to your other question, don't call `ShowWindow` from your `OnPaint`; it is there to paint ONLY.

Comment: @vla How do you hide the primary dialog of a dialog-based application, though (which is the essence of this question, even if it's not literally asking for that)?

Comment: yes, my programming skill level is low so I cannot solve this, as IInspectable said that's my question purpose

Comment: @IInspectable I've added a code sample here, although it wasn't asked :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can hide a main window of the dialog-based MFC app.

Add `bool` member variable to your dialog class:

```
bool m_bFirst = true;
```

Add handler for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message to your `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`:

```
ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING()
```

and declare it in the header file

```
afx_msg void OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos);
```

You can use a Class Wizard to add it to your class.

In the handler, enforce a flag to hide the window until you get a first hot key message:

```
void CMFCApplicationDlg::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    if (m_bFirst) {
        lpwndpos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
        lpwndpos->flags |= SWP_HIDEWINDOW;
    }
    CDialogEx::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
}
```

And finally reset that flag in your `WM_HOTKEY` handler:

```
void CMFCApplicationDlg::OnHotKey(UINT nHotKeyId, UINT nKey1, UINT nKey2)
{
    if (nHotKeyId == 1001) {
        m_bFirst = false;
        ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }
    else if (nHotKeyId == 1002)
        ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
```

**NOTE:**

I would **strongly** advise against using simple `MOD_SHIFT` modifier for the hot key: you will no longer be able to type upper-case `A` into any other apps.